# Replace Tag p to br in Blockquote

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to replace html tag `p` in `blockquote` with `br`, work with click `button`

**Before :**

```
<div id='tes'>
    <blockquote>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum one</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum two</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum <b>bold</b></p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
<button>Replace P</button>
```

**after :**

```
<div id='tes'>
    <blockquote>
        Lorem Ipsum one<br/>
        Lorem Ipsum two<br/>
        Lorem Ipsum <b>bold</b><br/>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can provide a function to the `replaceWith()` method that returns the current HTML content of the `p` tag, with an appended `<br />` at the end. Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('blockquote p').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).html() + '<br />';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tes'>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum one</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum two</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum <b>bold</b></p>
  </blockquote>
</div>
<button>Replace P</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do this. Get the text in an array and just join it:

```js
var $btn = $('button');

$btn.on('click', changeP2br);

function changeP2br(){
  var arr = $('#tes p').map(function(_,o){
     return o.innerHTML;
  }).get();
  $('#tes blockquote').html(arr.join('<br>'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tes'>
    <blockquote>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum one</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum two</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum <b>bold</b></p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
<button>Replace P</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, using `append` and `unwrap` to add the `<br/>` then remove the surrounding `<p>`.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('blockquote p').append('<br />');
  $('blockquote p>br').unwrap();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tes'>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum one</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum two</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum <b>bold</b></p>
  </blockquote>
</div>
<button>Replace P</button>
```

---

You could use `appendTo` and chain the `unwrap` for efficiency, but I kept it this way for clarity.